# c# Form return value?

Tags: c#, winforms, forms

I have one Form, that opens another one. The user writes some information here. When closing this second Form, on the first one, I need to use the previously added information.

(The added information is a string- an email address, and I would add it to listbox items in the first Form.)

I tried Close(), or Hide(). But no matter what was the order I got problems with the new Form closing when it opened, or it didn't open at all.

Comment: why you open form1 ? You expect the input from the user?

Comment: in form1 you can choose an email address from a listbox.
in form2 you can write in a textbox.(this will be the email)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could a string property to the form that will contain the value. It will simply expose the value of the private email field.

For example:

```
public class SomeForm : Form
{
    public string Email
    {
        get
        {
            return txtEmail.Text;
        }
    }
}
```

and then from some outside form you could show the form and read the value that was entered into the Email field once the form is closed:

```
using (var form = new SomeForm())
{
    if (form.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        string email = form.Email;
        // do something with the email
    }
}
```

Comment: It always skips it when it reaches the if condition for me.

Answer (score 0):

Get the value from `form1` and pass as `parameter` in `form2` constructor.See code below

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      string email = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
      Form2 secondForm = new Form2(email);
      this.Hide();
      secondForm.Show();
}
```

In Form2 constructor:

```
 public Form2(string email)
 {
       textbox2.text = email;
 }
```